# speech to text implementing in android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to implement a speech to text recognizer for my app but i keep getting an error about the R.menu.activity_main in the line before "return true", specifically about the MENU between R and activity_main. It mentions "class,enum excpected".

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtSpeechInput;
    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        // hide the action bar
        getActionBar().hide();

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     * */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `R.menu.activity_main` is not exist. First check in Resource folder under menu folder this activity_main exist or not.

Comment: Sorry but i cannot understand you. I believe I followed exactly the guidelines in this tutorial:https://coderanch.com/t/601843/java-code-speech-text

Comment: Check your Menu folder under Resource that this activity_main file exist or not.